# Is the following language context free?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-free

Is $L = \{ a^nb^nc^j \mid n \le j\}$ a context-free language? I'm getting really stuck generating a grammar for it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please not our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-questions) which cover your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ is not context free. You can use the [Ogden's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogden%27s_lemma) to show it.

I'll use the Wikipedia notation linked above.

For every $p$ take the word $a^pb^pc^p$. For a the marking where only c are marked whatever the decomposition $uxyzv$ you take, $ux^iyz^iv$ will not be in $L$.
Four cases: $z\in c^*$ then it fails for $i=0$ or $z\notin c^*$ then it fails for $i>0$. And the symmetric cases for $x$.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm assuming that the second piece a^nb^nc^2n can be disproved this way as well?

Comment: yep same proof should even be easier.

Comment: It seems the standard Pumping for context-free languages would work fine. Either pump $a$'s and $b$'s *up*, or $c$'s *down*.

Comment: @HendrikJan you are right. And its easier ...